# Export and import classes in React without ES6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm working on a react project but don't want to use `ES6`, because I don't really understand how it works. I want to export my class, ShoppingList, given below:

```
class ShoppingList extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="shopping-list">
                <h1>Shopping List for {this.props.name}</h1>
                <ul>
                    <li>Instagram</li>
                    <li>WhatsApp</li>
                    <li>Oculus</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I want to import this into my index.js:

```
const rootElement = document.getElementById('root')
const ShoppingList = require('./Components/ShoppingList')

function App() {
    return (
        <div>
            <ShoppingList name="Abhinav" />
        </div>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement)
```

But the `require()` function doesn't work. If anyone could tell me how to easily import ta function or how I could add ES6 to this. The image of the directory is given below:

[image]

Comment: why do you want to do that?

Comment: So why are you using classes if you don't want to use ES6? :)

Comment: oh, so only es6 mainly supports classes?

Comment: I suggest you to take a quick look at ES6 standards. As you are using class based components.

Comment: ok, so can tell me what i can add to shift to es6, i've done it with npm before, but dont have that now. Is there any file I can add to get es6?

Comment: `require` is a node.js feature that will not work in a browser. You should use some sort of transpiler to convert your code to something the browser can run like e.g. [babel](https://babeljs.io/)

Comment: I leave a downvote for this question, in fact, It is disgusting, react without `ES6+`. I offer you see some tutorials about EcmaScript and see AirBnB ESList code style and feel pure beauty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> dont want to use ES6, because I dont really understand how it works.

For this you have to take a look at the standards define for the language. [You can start here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/ECMAScript_2015_support_in_Mozilla). Most of the browswers today supports ES6+ features like class, fat arrow syntax, let, const etc.

For full support you have to set up any transpiler which is used to transpile latest standard code to working supported code. What this means is it will transpile the code to supported code for the browsers which does not understand the latest syntax.

For this you can use several tools like:

- Webpack
- Babel
- Typescript

etc. Typescript is a language which is a superset of javascript. It has all the latest features of javascript which is not yet released or supported.

> If anyone could tell me how to easily import a function or how I could add ES6 to this.

See, if you want to import any function or class then it **must** be exported first. So, if we take your code example then you have to export it like:

```
export class ShoppingList extends React.Component {
     // class code
}
```

or

```
class ShoppingList extends React.Component {}
export { ShoppingList }; // normal export
export default ShoppingList; // default export don't need {}
```

In the above code you can see two types of export first one is inline export and you can default export it too like `export default class ShoppingList ...`.

In the second example you can see two types of exports:

- Normal export will be exported within `{}` and imported in `{}` too.
- Default export will be exported without braces and imported without braces too.

Now you can import it like:

```
import { ShoppingList } from './path/of/file'; // normal import
import ShoppingList from './path/of/file'; // default exported import    
import SList from './path/of/file'; // name it anything but works only for default exports
```

Comment: I'm using babel already, but thats for JSX. How do I make it run ES6?

Comment: @Abhinav I would rather suggest you to use a tool `create-react-app`, it can generate a project for you and then you can start development in that. Go through the documentation you can find many things.

Comment: I've used create-react-app before and it's worked for me but currently I'm at a school where npm and node.js isn't installed on the computers. I've found a way to create a react app, but only this one thing is troubling me. But if I dont find any answer that works, I can just import through my html page, which works fine.

Comment: You can use online editors like stackblitz for this then.